# Не работает SQL-запрос

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть таблица в MySQL товаров вида
id|id_категории|имя|описание|

Нужно найти такие id_категории, что товаров, принадлежащих этой категории, например, ровно 2.

Пишу запрос:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`товары`.`id_категории`) AS `количество_товаров` FROM `товары` WHERE `количество_товаров` = 2 GROUP BY `id_категории` ORDER BY `количество_товаров`
```

Возвращает ошибку: "#1054 - Unknown column 'количество_товаров' in 'where clause'"

Если писать без условия WHERE, то запрос работает и выводит таблицу товаров вместе со счетчиком товаров:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`товары`.`id_категории`) AS `количество_товаров` FROM `товары` GROUP BY `id_категории` ORDER BY `количество_товаров`
```

Почему не работает условие по алиасу количество_товаров и как написать так, чтобы работало?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К псевдонимам запроса нельзя обращаться из конструкции `WHERE`. Если вы хотите результат агрегатной функции указать в условии,  то у Вас два варианта:

1. Обернуть это еще в один селект
2. Использовать [HAVING](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL)

Вот пример для второго варианта:

```
SELECT
   `id_категории`
   ,COUNT(*) `количество_товаров`
FROM
   `товары`
GROUP BY
   `id_категории`
HAVING
   COUNT(*) = 2
```